# How to make character continue moving after releasing key, in Slick2D?

Tags: java, slick2d

I am new to Slick2D and I am trying movements with my character. I can make it move smoothly while holding movement key, but I also want the character to finish its movement so it stops exactly on the next tile (I have simple map with tiles 32x32). And that is a problem for me, because it moves to the next tiles, but it teleports there - the movement is instant and I want my character to just continue with its movement with the same speed.

I tried for example something like this in my `update()` method:

```
else if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_D))
    {
        characterAnimation = characterAnimationRight;
        characterAnimation.update(delta);
        xCoord = (int) xCoord;
        while (xCoord%32 != 0)
        {
            xCoord += 1;
            characterAnimation.update(delta);
            if (xCoord > Window.WIDTH - 32)
            {
                xCoord = Window.WIDTH - 32;
            }

        }
    }
```

but I can´t make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not to calculate `xCoord` in `while()` in the `update()` method. The reason is that it is calculated in single run of `update()` method and after that the `render()` method is called to render the character. That means character is rendered after that `while()` and it teleports.

Here is my solution:

```
@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame s, int delta)
        throws SlickException {

    // .......

    if (moving)
    {
        if (movingDirection == DIR_RIGHT)
        {
            if (xCoord >= targetCoord)
            {
                xCoord = targetCoord;
                moving = false;
            }
            else
            {
                xCoord += delta * 0.1f;
                characterAnimation.update(delta);
                if (xCoord > Window.WIDTH - 32)
                {
                    xCoord = Window.WIDTH - 32;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (movingDirection == DIR_LEFT)
        {
            if (xCoord <= targetCoord)
            {
                xCoord = targetCoord;
                moving = false;
            }
            else
            {
                xCoord -= delta * 0.1f;
                characterAnimation.update(delta);
                if (xCoord < 0)
                {
                    xCoord = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (movingDirection == DIR_UP)
        {
            if (yCoord <= targetCoord)
            {
                yCoord = targetCoord;
                moving = false;
            }
            else
            {
                yCoord -= delta * 0.1f;
                characterAnimation.update(delta);
                if (yCoord < 0)
                {
                    yCoord = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (movingDirection == DIR_DOWN)
        {
            if (yCoord >= targetCoord)
            {
                yCoord = targetCoord;
                moving = false;
            }
            else
            {
                yCoord += delta * 0.1f;
                characterAnimation.update(delta);
                if (yCoord > Window.WIDTH - 32)
                {
                    yCoord = Window.WIDTH - 32;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Variable `moving` is set true after pressing movement key. Now after every call of `render()` the character is moved a little bit in the `update()` and rendered at this new position until it is exactly on the tile.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to have a "xSpeed" and "ySpeed" and set those values according to where the 'characterAnimation' is set to and to whether you are on an exact tile or not?

Something like:

```
else if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_D)) {
    characterAnimation = characterAnimationRight;
}

// ...

if (characterAnimation == characterAnimationRight){
    xSpeed = 1;
}
else if (characterAnimation == characterAnimationLeft){
    xSpeed = -1;
}
xCoord += xSpeed;
characterAnimation.update(delta);
if(xCoord % 32 == 0) {
    xSpeed = 0;
}
// ...
```

I do not actually know how your code (or slick2d) works, so I assumed the `xCoord` value is magically taken into account when `characterAnimation.update(delta)` is called. Otherwise do whatever you need to update your character's position according to `xCoord`.